# Java Path being set to python instead of java

Tags: java

When I am running a java program I am getting this path connecting it to python. I am trying to compile my program on sublime and I am getting this error

error: incompatible types: LinkedList cannot be converted to Queue
Queue q = new LinkedList();

I shouldn't be getting this issue according to java type rules I think. Is the python path what is causing this error? If not what could cause this. The path I am getting is listed below.

`[path: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin]`

Thanks!

Comment: You need to provide us some more details. What OS (and version) you are using? What IDE / compiler? How and where do you see this path? It looks like a normal path, nothing to with Python in particular. What error are you getting when compiling?

Comment: You are going to have to provide more details than that.

Comment: This looks like your regular OS `PATH` variable, and shouldn't affect Java or Python execution. For Java in particular, you should be ideally be looking at `JAVA_HOME`

Comment: how did you install java? It's possible there is an executable `/usr/bin/java` The fact you have a python added to your path is a completely separate issue.

Comment: Okay, this problem has nothing to do with your path. Can you include your complete program including your import statements. Yes a LinkedList is a Queue. Although the code you've written has syntax errors. `Queue<?> q = new LinkedList<>();` Notice that Queue is only written once. I've also included the `<>` for generics because you shouldn't use raw types.

Comment: A path error would mean, you couldn't run java. So your error would be along the lines of "java is not a known program..." etc.

Comment: Have you written your own class named `LinkedList` or `Queue`? Please show your entire code including imports.

Comment: @matt I think the first `Queue` is part of the error message.